# What kind of action is it to command a shark?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, actions

So, sahuagin all possess the shark telepathy trait, which states:

> Shark Telepathy. The sahuagin can magically command any
>   shark within 120 feet of [it/her/him], using a limited telepathy.

It's not part of the actions section for the sahuagin, and no action is given.  Should this be like the beastmaster having to use a bonus action each round thing, or more like the UA feat that lets you use a bonus action once and give a command that lasts a minute, or something else altogether?

Answer (score 8):

### No Action

Since no action is mentioned, there would be no reason to assume an action is required. I would view it similarly to how [Conjured Animals](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/spells/conjureAnimals.htm) and such are commanded: "*They obey any verbal commands that you issue to them (no action required by you)*".

Answer (score 2):

### No action required

“Shark Telepathy” is a “Special Trait” (MM p.10) of the creature: therefore it is not an action or reaction. As such it just happens, however, it is limited in the same way that talking is during combat - communication that could be done inside 6 seconds so no Shakespearean soliloquies.